# Encrypting connection strings for azure webapp

Tags: azure, encryption, connection-string, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to encrypt the connection strings of the web app hosted in azure. I found that this can be done using the aspnet_regiis.exe tool. But, my question is we have the auto scale out enabled and it happens quite often. So, If I encrypt the connection strings using the tool mentioned above, will it work if the webapp is scaled out. Is there any other way to encrypt?

Comment: I suggest storing the connection string in an [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to securely store your connection string you should use [**Azure Key Vault**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) (as mentioned by Peter Bons).

To safely access the credentials you should consider using [**Managed Identities**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview).
Here is the Managed Identities [documentation for App Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity)